# How to move marker in Leaflet along a circle?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, leaflet, mapbox

I am working on an application where I have a marker and a circle around it.

Now I am creating another marker on the circumference of the circle which is draggable. But I only want it to be draggable on the circumference itself.

```
var coords = [parseFloat(response.lat), parseFloat(response.long)];
terrainAnalysisMap.setView(coords, 18);
var marker = L.marker(coords).addTo(terrainAnalysisMap);
var circle = L.circle([parseFloat(response.lat), parseFloat(response.long)], parseFloat(response.radius)).addTo(terrainAnalysisMap);

convertRadiusToLatitude = parseInt(response.radius)/111111;

var coordsOnRadius = [parseFloat(response.lat) + convertRadiusToLatitude, parseFloat(response.long)];
var markerOnRadius = L.marker(coordsOnRadius, {draggable: true}).addTo(terrainAnalysisMap);
```

How to accomplish this? How to make the `markerOnRadius` draggable but only on the edge of the circle?

**OR**

I can introduce a small input field where the user can input the number of degrees and the marker will shift to that point on the circumference?

Even if someone can point me to the right algorithm and give me an idea of how to use it, I'll do it myself. I am just not that great at maths which is why I cannot figure this out.

**EDIT with code based on answer**

```
$('#terrainAnalysisAngle').on('keyup', function(e){
    var markerOnRadiusX = parseFloat(response.lat) + (0.000009 * parseFloat(response.radius)) * Math.cos($(this).val());
    var markerOnRadiusY = parseFloat(response.long) + (0.000009 * parseFloat(response.radius)) * Math.sin($(this).val());
    console.log([markerOnRadiusX, markerOnRadiusY]);
    markerOnRadius.setLatLng([markerOnRadiusX, markerOnRadiusY]);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parametric equations that give you the points along a circle's circumference are given by:

```
x = Xc + R * cos(theta)
y = Yc + R * sin(theta)
```

Where, x,y is a point on the circumference, Xc, Yc is the centre of the circle, R is its radius and theta is the angle.

To have a point (or small dot) draggable in a circuimference you need to know, the centre of your GUI element (this will be your Xc, Yc), the radius of your GUI element (this will be your R) and the angle between the centre of your GUI element and the current position of the mouse pointer (this will be your theta).

To work out the angle between the current mouse pointer position with respect to Xc, Yc, you can evaluate the angle's tangent and then use the arctan function to recover the angle. To do this you need to evaluate the arctan of (currentMouseY - Yc) / (currentMouseX - Xc).

You then have all the data required to put a marker at the circumference of the circle.

The input field solution is even more straightforward because there you can relate your quantity's range (say for instance 0-100) with theta's range (0-360) through a very simple linear relationship and set theta to its right value directly.

For more information please see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation) and [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle.html).

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE:**

I am assuming that the graphical element will not become part of the chart. In other words, it is not a feature that will have to be bounded to a particular geographic location. In this case, you don't have to use Leaflet to draw the GUI element's circles and you could translate between World  (chart coordinates) and Window coordinates through the data attached to the [mousemove](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#mouse-event) event. You could also use Leaflet's Circle and Line feature drawing capabilities in this case, because you can move easily between World and Window coordinates. In this case, please see [Leaflet's quickstart](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html) in combination with this response. Finally, you might find [this mapbox example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/mouse-position/) illustrative as well.

**UPDATE 2:**

**What (I think) is required:** 
A simple chart view provided by Leaflet. When the user clicks on a point on the chart, a circular GUI element appears with a marker along its circumference. The user moves the marker along the circuimference to enter a value. The GUI element is to vanish after the user enters the value. The GUI element is not a feature of the chart. In other words, it doesn't have to "scroll" along with the map and be "bound" to a particular geographical location.

**How to proceed:** The above explanation of how to move a marker along the circumference of a circle is still valid. The "problem" now is how to position the element on the chart. There are actually two coordinate systems at work here. One is the "World" coordinate system, which is expressed in terms of Longitude and Lattitude. The other is the "Window" coordinate system which is the x,y coordinates with respect to the top-left corner of the window that contains the chart. Therefore:

1. Setup a leaflet window that shows the chart at some default location
2. Setup a listener for the appropriate mouse events (left button down, left button up and move)
3. Within the mouse listeners, retrieve both the WORLD and WINDOW coordinates of where the mouse pointer is. Perhaps [this example](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/mouse-position/) is helpful.
4. If you want to draw the circle using leaflet's geographical feature's option then use the WORLD coordinates and code similar to what is presented [here](http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start.html). The idea of drawing the circle, its marker in its periphery and how that moves along with user input does not change, only the coordinate system changes.
5. If you were to use some other library or set of functions, to draw within the DIV that contains the map itself, then all you have to do is use the WINDOW coordinates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your parametric equations for converting the points along the circle's circumference are simple enough, but I still have the problem that my Xc and Yc are points on the globe (latitude, longitude) and the radius I have is in metres and not latitude, longitude.

Comment: I am sorry for the misunderstanding, perhaps I did not really get the point from the description. I have amended my response but still based on an assumption :) Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow. I apologize but I cannot understand most of things you said. The thing is I have a main marker (pivot) and another marker on my map which rests, say 100 metres to the north of the pivot and I have an input box which has a value of 0. Now say, the user enters 90, I would like to calculate the coordinates 100 metres to the east of the pivot, or if he enters 180, coordinates 100 metres south of the pivot. I hope I am making sense. You clearly know your maths, how do I do that? Thank you for your help anyway. :)

Comment: NewLong = pivotLong + 0.0009 * cos(angle-pi/2), NewLat = pivotLat + 0.0009 * sin(angle-pi/2). The adjustment is to align with North and 0.0009 is 1 meter in degrees. I think that you will be able to implement either solutions by now :)

Comment: This might just work. I am sorry if this is dumb but what is angle-pi/2? Are you saying ((angle*pie)/2)? Or is it something else? Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, I am saying what I wrote :) And it's not a dumb question. The way the system is written above it transcribes the unit circle clockwise but starts at 3 o'clock, or East, by default. On a chart, 0 degrees is North (or 12 o'clock). So, to have 0 degrees coincide with North (in a clockwise system), I subtract 1/4 of a circle (or pi/2) from the angle. If that's not clear, please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system

Comment: I am still a little confused. I have edited my question with what I doing with my code based on the parametric equations but I don't think I am getting the desired result. Could you kindly look at it and point out where I am going wrong? And I think 1 meter in deg is 0.000009.

Comment: Okay I wasn't converting the deg to radians in the cos and sin function. Now I did. Works like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: No worries, 0.000009 is indeed 1meter but you mentioned a 100 meter radius somewhere...Glad it was of help anyway.

Comment: I have one small problem if you have any idea about it. The formula is working but it is slightly off. The longitudes are slightly off. The latitudes are being plotted perfectly. The longitudes are always a little less than they should be and it increases and decreases. To give you better idea, visualize the increment of the angle from 0 - 180 and the marker starts to come near to centre till 90 and then start moving back again till it is perfect at 180 again. So basically it calculating the lat, long as if it were an ellipse. Any idea how to correct this?